# Using a typedef – based on template-patameter for class – outside scope of class

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, typedef

How can I use a `typedef`, which is based upon a template parameters for my class, in both the declaration and definition of class functions?

suppose my class is:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    typedef T::T1 X;
    typedef T::T2 Y;

    X& f1(Y& y);
    Y& f2(Y& y);

    // More declarations
};
```

So in the definitions, I can't just write:

```
typedef typename T::T1 X;
typedef typename T::T2 Y;

template<class T>
X& A<T>::f1(Y& y) {...}

template<class T>
Y& A<T>::f2(Y& y) {...}
```

(In my case `T` is `MaxSimplePathVertex<VertexType<VertexIDType>>`, and I have 3 more typedefs, so it's really cumbersome).

I guess I can duplicate all the typedefs *into* each function definition, but that doesn't seem like an elegant solution.

And, of course, I can do `#define X T1`, but usually I hear people recommend against using `#define` for those sort of things.

So what is the best solution?

Comment: `template<typename T> using X = typename MaxSimplePathVertex<VertexType<T>>::X;` ? Alternatively `auto A<T>::f1(Y &y) -> X& { ... }`

Comment: Is [`typename A<T>::X`](http://ideone.com/mASNyY) too cumbersome ? (slightly related, you're missing your `typename`s in your example). It is entirely possible I completely misunderstood the problem, fyi).

Comment: @WhozCraig, thanks, I fixed the misinformation,
but I don't really understand where to write what you proposed.

Comment: @DrorFelman the link in my prior comment would be what I was referring to.

Answer (score 5):

Trailing return types are a real day saver when you deal with templates and member typedefs in return types. You can simply say

```
template<class T>
auto A<T>::f1(Y& y) -> X& {...}

template<class T>
auto A<T>::f2(Y& y) -> X& {...}
```

Things that appear after the member function name are looked up in the `A<T>` template, which means you don't need to put the `A<T>::` in front of them.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know that. Is it true since C++11 or, later?

Comment: @Nawaz from what I know, since C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Spelling it out fully, because when the return type precedes the method definition, the type is evaluated in the current namespace, not the namespace of the class's method:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    typedef typename T::T1 X;
    typedef typename T::T2 Y;

    X& f1(Y& y);
    Y& f2(Y& y);

    // More declarations
};

template<class T>
typename A<T>::X& A<T>::f1(Y& y) {}

template<class T>
typename A<T>::Y& A<T>::f2(Y& y) {}


struct Foo
{
    using T1 = int;
    using T2 = double;
};

int main()
{
    A<Foo> a;
}
```

But when we use the trailing return type, the return type is evaluated in the context of the method's class, so it gets easier:

```
template<class T>
class A
{
    typedef typename T::T1 X;
    typedef typename T::T2 Y;

    X& f1(Y& y);
    Y& f2(Y& y);

    // More declarations
};

template<class T>
auto A<T>::f1(Y& y) -> X&  // <-- this X is a A<T>::X
{}

template<class T>
auto A<T>::f2(Y& y) -> Y& {}


struct Foo
{
    using T1 = int;
    using T2 = double;
};

int main()
{

    A<Foo> a;
}
```

Comment: Is the `auto auto` a typo? Because I don't understand why you put 2 of them.

Comment: It is a typo, and oddly it did compile!